We know that $g \in L_1$ and that $g*g \leq g$ nearly everywhere. Show that: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) d\lambda_1(x) \leq 1$
$g \in L_1$ such that $g*g \leq g$ nearly everywhere. Show that:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) d\lambda_1(x) \leq 1$$
From what is said, I know that:
$$g*g \leq g \implies \int_{\mathbb{R}} (g*g) (x) \ d\lambda_1(x) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \ d\lambda_1(x)$$
From convolution definition we know that:
$$(g*g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x - y) g(y) \ d(y) \leq g(x)$$
Therefore, our inequality becomes:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x - y) g(y) \ d(y) \right) \ d\lambda_1(x) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \ d\lambda_1(x)$$
I think that since function $g \in L_1$ is Lebesgue integrable, we can change the order of integration and get:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x - y) g(y) \ d\lambda_1(x) \right) \ d(y) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \ d\lambda_1(x)$$
As it was noticed by Michael Burr in the comment below, $g(y)$ is constant with respect to x, so it is a constant that can be moved outside the integral, so we get:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x - y) \ d\lambda_1(x) \right) \ d(y) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \ d\lambda_1(x)$$
Then if it was true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x - y) \ d\lambda_1(x)$ was a constant with respect to $y$, so it could be moved outside the integral also and we would get:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) d(y) \cdot \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x - y) \ d\lambda_1(x) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \ d\lambda_1(x)$$
My guess is that we want to have that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x - y) \ d\lambda_1(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \ d\lambda_1(x)$ and then we would obtain the inequality that we were interested in. For that to be true we would need $y$ to be constantly equal to $0$. That would also explain why $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x - y) \ d\lambda_1(x)$ would be a constant with respect to $y$... but why would that be the case? Why $y$ would be constantly equal to $0$ in our case?
Any help would be appreciated.

Hints: In the inner integral, $g(y)$ is constant with respect to $x$, so it is a constant that can be moved outside the integral.  Then the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x-y)d\lambda_1(x)$ is independent of $y$ (why is this true).

By assumption,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x-y)g(x) \, dx \leq g(y)\quad \mbox{for almost every}~y.  
$$
Thus, put $I =\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) \, dy$. You have by Fubini's theorem that
$$
I^2 = \Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) \, dy \Big)^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x-y) g(x) \, dx dy  \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) \, dy = I.
$$
Thus, $I^2 \leq I$, and so  $I \in [0, 1]$.

Why do we know that it's true that: $\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) , dy \Big)^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x-y) g(x) , dx dy$ ? @DrewBrady

@thefool Fubini: $\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(x-y)g(x),dx,dy=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(x-y)g(x),dy,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(x)\left(\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(x-y),dy\right),dx$. For each fixed $x$, make a change of variables $y=x-z$ to see that the bracket equals $\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(z),dz$, which is a constant, and so the whole thing is $\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(x),dx\cdot\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(z),dz=I^2$. And if you wonder why Fubini is applicable, put absolute values everywhere first, then Tonelli tells us we can make the swap; then since $g\in L^1$, we have the result is finite, and thus Fubini can be applied.

Precisely as explained by peek-a-boo above

Ok, I see that. Thank you!
